# SASS conditional when parameters are eg: 1a and 1

Tags: sass

In mixin `@if $param==x ... @else if $param==y`, when x is a string starting with a number (1a), and y a pure number as the leading number in x (1), the conditional falls into the wrong block.  Is it a bug or intended?

```
@mixin view($view) {
  $bp_1a: 300px;
  $bp_1: 600px;

  @if $view == 1a {
    @media only screen and (max-width: $bp_1a - 1) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $view == 1 {
    @media only screen and (max-width: $bp_1 - 1) { @content; }
  }
}

@include view(1) { max-width: 1; }

---> compiled css

@media only screen and (max-width: 299px) {
  max-width: 1;
}
```

---

```
@mixin view($view) {
  $bp_1a: 300px;
  $bp_1: 600px;

  @if $view == a1 {
    @media only screen and (max-width: $bp_1a - 1) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $view == 1 {
    @media only screen and (max-width: $bp_1 - 1) { @content; }
  }
}

@include view(1) { max-width: 1; }

---> compiled css

@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  max-width: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that sass assumes *1a* is *1* in the conditional. If you want to put *1a* as a string, you have to add quotes to the value:

```
@mixin view($view) {
  $bp_1a: 300px;
  $bp_1: 600px;

  @if $view == "1a" {
    @media only screen and (max-width: $bp_1a - 1) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $view == 1 {
    @media only screen and (max-width: $bp_1 - 1) { @content; }
  }
}

@include view(1) { max-width: 1; }
```

Comment: Tested the following ok.  `@if $view == '1a' {...}   @include view('1a') {...}`  That means in `@include view('1a')` you are passing the string `quote-1-a-quote`.  I would say "sass assumes 1a is 1 in the conditional" is rather strange.